# Soft sheaf in locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

For a locally compact space $X$, I’ve seen two definitions of soft sheaf in different books: restriction map to closed subset is surjective or restriction map to compact subset is surjective. I wonder are they equivalent?

Thank you!